# Importing multiple files

Tags: r

I have about thirty folders and in each folder there is a number of files that each contain a matrix of different information.  I need to be able to import those files so I can do an image plot of the matrices.  I know how to do the image plot, but I don't know how to get all the files.  Is there a way to loop through each folder and grab the individual files i need from each one?  This is yearly meteorological data.  So what I have are yearly folders and each folder contains the same variables.  I need a loop that can pull the temperature file from the 2005 folder then pull the temperature file from the 2006 folder and so on.  Can this be done with a for loop or apply?

Comment: Can you show the format of the names of the folders and of the files in them? (Are they something like `temp2005`, `temp2006`, or whatever?)

Comment: The folders 2005152, 2005182, 2005312, 2006152, 2006182 and so on. They are folders that represent three months of the year.  The files in need in each folder is titled Cirrus_Reflective-_Mean_Daily.mat

I know how to import .mat files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `?list.dirs` and the related function `list.files` (both are documented in the same help page.)

First list the directories, e.g.:

```
> (dirs <- list.dirs("~/foo", recursive = FALSE))
[1] "/home/gavin/foo/bar1" "/home/gavin/foo/bar2"
```

Then loop over these, list the files in the current directory and read into a list, e.g.

```
loadFiles <- function(dirs) {
  fs <- list.files(dirs, full.names = TRUE, no.. = TRUE)
  lapply(fs, read.table, ....)
}
fs <- lapply(dirs, loadFiles)
```

Substitute `read.table` for whatever function is required to read the files, replace `....` with additional arguments to `read.table` (or the relevant function).

You can then use `rapply` to loop over `fs` to do the plotting.

<strike>Note none of the above is tested as there was no reproducible example I could quickly throw into a few files and folders to test it.</strike>

Here is an example with this kind of setup

```
> list.dirs("~/foo", recursive = FALSE)
[1] "/home/gavin/foo/bar1" "/home/gavin/foo/bar2"
> list.files("~/foo/bar1")
[1] "file1.csv" "file2.csv" "file3.csv"
> list.files("~/foo/bar2")
[1] "file1.csv" "file2.csv" "file3.csv"

loadFiles <- function(dirs) {
  fs <- list.files(dirs, full.names = TRUE, no.. = TRUE)
  lapply(fs, function(x) data.matrix(read.csv(x, row.names = 1)))
}
fs <- lapply(list.dirs("~/foo", recursive = FALSE), loadFiles)
```

`fs` now looks like this:

```
> str(fs)
List of 2
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : num [1:5, 1:5] -1.65 -2.47 1.27 0.14 -0.22 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
  ..$ : num [1:5, 1:5] 0.417 0.186 -2.452 -0.695 -1.216 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
  ..$ : num [1:5, 1:5] 1.41924 -1.96918 0.38819 -0.41437 0.00718 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : num [1:5, 1:5] -1.791 0.805 0.302 -0.383 -0.793 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
  ..$ : num [1:5, 1:5] 0.305 0.353 -0.342 0.515 -0.375 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
  ..$ : num [1:5, 1:5] -0.634 -0.776 0.517 -0.845 0.83 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
```

I haven't quite worked out how to get `rapply()` to work here, but

```
lapply(fs, function(x) lapply(x, image))
```

will plot  each of the 3 matrices in each of the two lists.

Comment: If each file is a 10 by 10 matrix how would I put them into an array.  Using your example, how would I put each file1.csv into a matrix.  This worked great, but it lists out each individual matrix.

Comment: @user2113499 can you start a new question for that please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180583/importing-mustiple-matricies-to-one-array-in-r

This is where the new question is.

Comment: I figured it out! This helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On windows:

Assuming you have yearly folders in `D:/data` and each folder has file by name `temperature.csv`

```
# set the main working directory
setwd("D:/data")

# allocate a list for temperature matrices
list.temp.matrix = vector("list",length(list.dirs(recursive=FALSE)))

# iterate through each folder and load the file
i <- 1
for (dir.name in list.dirs(recursive=FALSE))
{
    file.name <- paste0(dir.name, "/temperature.csv")
    temp.matrix <- as.matrix(read.csv(file.name))

    # update the list
    list.temp.matrix[[i]] <- temp.matrix
    i <- i + 1

    # to avoid over-writing plots
    x11()                                       
    image(temp.matrix)
}
```

Comment: You mean inside `setwd()`?

Comment: I mean everywhere (for directory paths on Windows).

Comment: Done. for some reason when I copy from explorer I get this \, so I am used to adding another \ instead of replacing it with `/`

Comment: That might eventually bite you.  It's a problem when you pass the text to a shell, that shell passes the text to another shell.  You end up in escape hell.

Comment: This works but I only get one matrix.  I apologize for not being specific in my original question.  Each file in each folder is a 10x10 matrix.  I need to get each matrix and put them into an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking to have all of the files read as data frames into the current session you could do something like this. I made a temporary directory called temp

```
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/homedir/tmp"
```

It has in it 3 directories with data from different years.

```
> dir()
[1] "data2005" "data2006" "data2007"
```

In these are saved some files (they're identical for the purpose of the example.

```
> ddfwind <- data.frame(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))
> ddfsun <- data.frame(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))
```

Saving these files to the directories to set up the example...

```
> lapply(dir(), function(x) {
+       save(ddfwind, file=paste(x,"wind.dat",sep="/"))
+       save(ddfsun,file=paste(x,"sun.dat",sep="/"))
+ })
```

In a new R session, I went to the directory tmp and got all of the files that have wind in their names from all directories

```
> fn.windData <- dir(pattern="wind.dat$", recursive=TRUE)
```

Then I used `lapply` to iterate through these files and load them into the current R session, appending the year of each onto the end of the data frame object.

```
> lapply(fn.windData, function(x) {
+ L1 <- load(x) 
+ assign(paste0(L1, gsub("[a-z./]", "", x)), get(L1), envir=.GlobalEnv)
+ })
> ls()
[1] "ddfwind2005" "ddfwind2006" "ddfwind2007" "fn.windData"
```