# Importing mutiple matrices to one array in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have one folder and in that folder there are 24 individual folders.  Each of those individual folders contains multiple files that each contain a matrix.  How can I loop through the individual folders and pull out select files and put them into an array?  For example, if I have one central folder and in that I have 24 folders and in each of the 24 folders there are files named file1, file2, file3, how can I pull off each file1 and put them into an array?

Comment: They are each 10 by 10

Comment: Yes it is.  One of the replies asked if I could start a new question for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
files <- list.files(path="/path/to/your/folder/")
require(abind)
arr <- do.call( abind, lapply(seq_along(list.files) , function(finum) {
                    data.matrix( read.table(file=files[finum],  ,,,devilish details) )
                    }
```

The request for the structure of the typical file is to fill in the devilish details. Could probably do it more directly since my first effort was initially thinking about using `abind` sequentially. Perhaps:

```
files <- list.files(path="/path/to/your/folder/")
require(abind)
arr <- do.call( abind, lapply(list.files , function(filnm) {
                    data.matrix( read.table(file=filnm,  ,,, devilish details) )
```